# Java android ROOM get object with detais

Tags: java, android, android-room

I have this :

```
    @Entity(tableName = "director"/*,
            indices = {@Index(value = "full_name", unique = true)}*/)
    public class Director {
        @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
        @ColumnInfo(name = "did")
        public int id;
        @ColumnInfo(name = "full_name")
        @NonNull
        public String fullName;


@Entity(tableName = "movie",
        foreignKeys = @ForeignKey(entity = Director.class,
                parentColumns = "did",
                childColumns = "directorId",
                onDelete = ForeignKey.CASCADE),
        indices = {@Index("title"), @Index("directorId")})
public class Movie {
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    @ColumnInfo(name = "mid")
    public int id;
    @ColumnInfo(name = "title")
    @NonNull
    public String title;
    @ColumnInfo(name = "directorId")
    public int directorId;
```

Amd when I get all movies I get director id . What I should to do to generate this :

```
public class MovieWithDirector {

    Movie movie;
    Director director;
}
```

I can get a user and later get directerByID but I don not now if this is a the best way to do this

Answer (score 0):

I would say that better way to perform this action is to write query with join:

```
SELECT  movie.title, director.fullname 
FROM director 
INNER JOIN movie 
ON movie.directorId=director.id 
WHERE director.id= :passed_value
```

Of course you will need custom class to for storing query result. 
If you check example from this [link](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room/accessing-data#query-multiple-tables), and combine with query above then you'll be able to solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to use **@Relation**

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/persistence/room/Relation